# how to use foreach method in lambda expression in c#- how use in current element

Tags: c#

```
ids.ForEach(objects.AddRange(Getobjects().FindAll(obj => obj.ImageID == );
```

"i want obj.ImageID == ids.currentId.
i mean ids is int array and i want in each iteration compare with ids[i]."

Comment: Where's the "x =>" part of your ForEach lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a classc foreach everything is pretty clear:

```
foreach(var id in ids)
    objects.AddRange(Getobjects().FindAll(obj => obj.ImageID == id));
```

If you really want the `ForEach`-extension-method - which I can´t assume why you should - here is it:

```
ids.ForEach(x => objects.AddRange(Getobjects().FindAll(obj => obj.ImageID == x)));
```

You can also use `Where` instead of `FindAll`, as the latter has the overhead of creating a new list:

```
objects.AddRange(Getobjects().Where(obj => obj.ImageID == id);
```